# WSGI - Should everything go below the "environ" line so that nothing is cached "globally"?

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, python-2.6

Recently i found out that placing python code above this line

```
def application(environ, start_response):
```

will result in things being cached in 8 threads.

Based on my apache error-log file.. i reloaded my wsgi script over and over again and realized 8 threads ( processes ) are created by wsgi script.

in other words this code below..

```
import os
ooo = os.popen('/text-file.txt').read()

def application(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    yield ooo
```

the contents of text-file.txt are actually

```
cached
```

in 8 different threads.

after wsgi script creates 8 different threads and caches this 8 different times.. it picks one randomly out of the 8 cached and thus it does not even matter if

```
/text-file.txt
```

is modified, updated.. etc..

the solution seems to be placing the

```
     ooo = os.popen('/text-file.txt').read()
```

under the environ line just like this:

```
import os

def application(environ, start_response):
    ooo = os.popen('/text-file.txt').read()
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    yield ooo
```

this above code works fine.

```
ooo = os.popen('/text-file.txt').read()
```

is based on a real time reading of the file and nothing is cached in 8 processes 8 different times.

the question here is...

if i have like too many lines such as

```
ooo = os.popen('/text-file.txt')
ooo2 = ooo.read()
ooo3 = "something"
ooo4 = "something else"
```

i mean basically this whole thing would have to go under the

environ line

but what if i have 40 of these for example in a wsgi script.  here's what it would look like assuming they are all different things..

```
import os

def application(environ, start_response):
        ooo = os.popen('/text-file.txt')
        ooo2 = ooo.read()
        ooo3 = "something"
        ooo4 = "something else"
    start_response('200 OK', [('content-type', 'text/html')])
    yield ooo
```

if there are too many things like that.. should they all be placed under the

```
     def application(environ, start_response):
```

or should they be called via

```
 functions ?
```

or does it simply not matter ?

what would be the method to create speedest codes ?

Comment: Yes, Python modules are cached. That is the point of using WSGI, to not have to re-run a new Python interpreter for each request.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, but it is not just the module. it is the contents of the file being read also being cached. where have you heard of some concept such as this in this world or in this universe ?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, were you trying to say.. " feed the file path to a class or a function that is defined above the environ line " ?

Comment: That's because you put that code at the module level. That code is only ever executed once. *where have you heard of some concept such as this in this world or in this universe* sounds like you have misunderstood something about how Python modules work.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, but what exactly is it caching up there ( above the environ line ).. how can modules even be cached.. are modules made up of strings or what

Comment: A module is a Python object. It is loaded into memory. It contains other Python objects, such as functions, classes, strings, etc. It is *just a namespace*.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, if i place my mysql connection above the environ line.. will my whole mysql be cached or is it simply a connection to the mysql. but what is the point of caching a connection to the mysql. it is simply a username and few other characters such as database name and so on.. do they really need to be cached.

Comment: There is no 'above the environ line' here. You defined a function. That function is called to handle requests. Anything outside of the function and at the module level, is, by definition, not part of the function and part of the module, and thus stored as a global name in the module. So yes, a MySQL connection object is stored there.

Comment: You are missing **fundamental concepts** about the Python datamodel. I suggest you go back to the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) and pay attention to how Python's model works. If you are feeling adventurous, go study the [Python datamodel](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html). Python WSGI applications are **not single webpages executed each time a request comes in**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything at the top-level of a Python module is loaded just once, when the module is imported. **This is by design**.

The WSGI server imports your module once per process, then calls your `application` method to handle requests. If data needs to be 'fresh' for each request, *do not use module globals*.

How you then build your data per request, is entirely up to you. Using functions to partition your logic and make code re-usable, sounds like a darn good idea.

Comment: if this concept was in reality would this be equivalent of using the same basket to transport washed socks from the dishwasher to the balcony then taking that same basket and transporting something else to somewhere else ?

Comment: i see i see.. the path to the balcony from the dishwasher is being memorized and here in wsgi and python it is being memorized as well.. caching is same as memorizing

Comment: No, the Python module is a robot you can program. The `application` function is the subroutine that handles carrying the washing basket. A robot needs to have all sorts of procedures it can call upon, as well as store data on how to get to the balcony. You call the `application` function every time you want washing taken over, but the robot doesn't need to be told how to get to the balcony each time you do that, or how to hold the basket, or how to empty the basket once there.

Comment: well the human being is a robot that memorizes things and caches them in the brain. this is why it is more convenient to wash many things at once rather than at different times. the human mind caches how the dish was washed.. all it has to do is repeat the process after having cached the previous execution.

Comment: in a function defined above the environ line.. lets say the environ line is the kitchen line.. inside the kitchen how the dish is washed is memorized. but this same function can be used to wash the other dishes. i get it now.